# $0$-Place Constant Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X = \{\ldots, a, \ldots \}$ and $f$ be a $0$-place function with constant value $a$ on $X$.

Does this literally just mean that $f = \{\{a\}\}$?  That is, the fact $f$ is a "$0$" place function just means that $f$ doesn't take any arguments.  So we have $f = \{(a)\} = \{\{a\}\}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: In the a first-order language, we may have constant symbols, function symbols of various "arities" (for functions of $1$ variable, $2$ variables, and so on. We may also have preicate symbols of various arities. Instead of constant symbols, some people like to talk of function symbols of arity $0$. Cute, kind of, but it makes no difference. In any structure, they are interpreted as constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifying $0$ and $\emptyset$, this means $f:X^0\to X$, and for each $t\in X^0$ we have $f(t)=a$. Since $X^0=\{0\}$, this means $f:\{0\}\to X$ and $f(0)=a$, or $f=\{(0,a)\}=\{\{\{0\},\{0,a\}\}\}$, if we insist.

Comment: To be clear, you are using $0$ and $\emptyset$ interchangeably here (that's what you meant by "identifying $0$ and $\emptyset$?).  Is this correct?

Comment: @user1770201 Yes. This is a more or less standard convention, I hope it is not confusing you. To be explicit, $X^0=\{\emptyset\}$, and the last $6$ zeros should be empty sets.